# Sparkfun SC16IS750 interrupt pin IRQ not working

Tags: c, arduino, embedded

I am facing problems using sc16is750 breakout board. I want to use the interrupt method mentioned in the datasheet. According to which, the IRQ pin should be active low whenever Rx or Tx pins are active, and an Interrupt should be generated.

But the IRQ pin remains high nonetheless. I have set up an external 1k ohm pull-up resistor as mentioned with 3.3v VDD.

My goal is to use vk16e gps module through spi pins on an arduino uno. I have set up the low interrupt on digital pin 2 and it is working fine. If I manually connect this pin to the ground, the gps data appears successfully. But not with the IRQ pin.

Comment: I am using UART_Bridge library from Sandbox Electronics from GitHub for arduino.

Comment: A fast look to the [manual at page 15](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf): `IER` and `IOIntEna` enables the interrupt source: did you write them with correct values.  `IIR[5:0]` is responsible for defining the type of interrupt: did you set it correctly?

Comment: There are two functions defined in the library source file mentioned above. void SetPinInterrupt(uint8_t io_int_ena)
void SetInterruptControl(uint8_t int_ena)

These functions are responsible for writing values to the registers you mentioned. SetPinInterrupt is I think for the I/O pin related interrupts. I used the second function to enable the Rx Tx interrupt by writing 0x04 to the IER register.

The problem is this keeps the IRQ pin constantly low, even when data is not present.

Comment: @LPs Can you please guide me what values should be written to these registers?

Comment: Looking at the man (pag 29) `IER` set to `4` means: _enable the receiver line status interrupt_

Comment: At page 15 you have table 6 that explains values for IIR[5:0]. I don't know the right one for you...

Comment: Thank you very much. 1 value worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Finally I found out that the interrupt pin on the breakout board is not connected to the 2kOhm IRQ pull up. 
I added a white wire and now it works fine.

Comment: Even the alibaba clone boards repeat this mistake :-(